# CSS: is there a way to include :before dimensions to element with position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  top: 300px;
}
#foo:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <a href="#">Link to something</a>
</div>
```

Is there a rule for element with `position: absolute` to include what is inside `:before` pseudo-class to it's dimensions? Now #foo height only includes anchor element.

**EDIT**
:before has negative top margin, so that link would still appear at exactly top: 300px.

Comment: Here on chrome, the `#foo` is considering the dimensions of `:before` as well.

Comment: You can position a `:before` pseudo-element relative an absolutely positioned element, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me - give a background color to #foo and you will see that the link has been pushed down 100px

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Actually, the **foo:before** in your code was working. You just cant see anything because the **content** style in **foo:before** was set empty or there's no other css styles to make it visible somehow.

```css
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  top: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
#foo:before {
  content: "asd";
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <a href="#">Link to something</a>
</div>
```